# How to find the set of tuples which has the same specific values in the same specific positions as another tuple?

Tags: python, tuples

I have a set of tuples of length N, in this simplified example, N = 3.

```
tuple_list = [('A','',''),('A','B',''),('A','','B'),('A','C','B'),...]
```

If I choose a specific tuple

```
chosen_tuple = ('A','','')
```

How do I find all the tuples in `tuple_list` which has the same value in the same position as `chosen_tuple` where the value is not `''` and is not the same value as `chosen_tuple`?

So with the assumption that the set of possible letters are `{A,B,C}` and N=3 and a letter can only be present once in a tuple that would give me

```
found_tuples = [('A','B','C'),('A','C','B'),('A','','C'),('A','','B'),('A','B',''),('A','C','')]
```

If instead

```
chosen_tuple = ('A','','B')
```

I would want

```
found_tuples = [('A','C','B')]
```

What is the best way of doing this for a generic N and set of letters?

Comment: are the value in the set always string? of size one or 0?

Comment: The values at each position are always strings, not sure what you mean by size one or 0?

Comment: In the last example, why just `[('A','C','B')]` and not  `[('A','C','B'), ('A','','B')]`?

Comment: Good catch, I will edit the question to fix this.

Comment: is it only on letter or empty string or can it be word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is a variant:

```
def select(item, chosen_tuple):
    for element, chosen in zip(item, chosen_tuple):
        if chosen == '':
            continue
        if element != chosen:
            return False
    return True


res = [item for item in tuple_list if select(item, chosen_tuple)]
```

write a list-comprehension with a filter function that i call `select`.

`select` iterates over the pairs of the elements from the current item in the list and the elements of the chosen tuple.